Give an example of $P_m$ and $f_n$ so that $\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n dP_m\neq \int fdP$
Let $(X,\mathcal{F})$ be a measurable space. Let $\{P_m\}_{m=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of probability measures so that $P_m\to P$ weakly as $m\to\infty$. Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of continuous uniformly bounded functions $f_n: X\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f_n\to f$ a.s. Show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}\int f_n dP_m=\int fdP$$.
Give an example of $P_m$ and $f_n$ so that $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n dP_m\neq \int fdP$$

I try to prove the question: since $P_m\to P$ weakly, then
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}\int f_n dP_m=\int f_n dP
$$
Then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty}\int f_n dP_m=\lim_{n\to\infty} \int f_n dP
$$
Since $|f_n|\le C$ for all $n$ and $\int CdP<\infty$, then by dominated convergence theroem
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int f_n dP=\int f dP
$$
Is this proof ok? Also, how to find such example so that they are not equal after swapping the order of limits?

What does a.s. mean here?

Arrange $f$ to be a step function and $P_m$ some Dirac deltas. This will give you a counterexample.

@geetha290krm That is almost surely (i.e., it holds with probability one)

With respect to what measure? a.s  does not make sense.

@geetha290krm Why this is wrong? Can you please point out the wrong in my proof? Thank you!

@geetha290krm I think that should be a.s. with P$?

Yes. a.s [P]. Your argument is fine, I mis-read. Now follow the hint above for a counter-example.

@SeverinSchraven Can you please write it in details? Thank you!

Curious: is $\mathcal{F}$ supposed to be a Borel $\sigma$-algebra of some topological space $(X,\tau)$?

@BrianMoehring Exactly!

@H.YDuan Is it clear now?

If we change the order of the limits we are asking about
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int f dP_n=\int f dp.$$
If $f$ is continuous, then this holds true by the weak convergence of $P_n$ to $P$. Hence we need to pick some discontinuous function $f$. The most classical example for weak convergence is a sequence of Dirac deltas. Namely, if $x_n\rightarrow y$ and $g$ is continuous, then
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int g d\delta_{x_n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} g(x_n)=g(y)=\int g d \delta_y.$$
Here we have crucially used the continuity of $g$ and this gives us the right idea to construct a counterexample.
Let $X=[-1/2,1/2]$ with $\mathcal{F}$ the Borel-sigma algebra. Furthermore, define
$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} 0,& x\in [-1/2,0],\\ \min \{ 1, nx \},& x\in (0,1/2]. \end{cases}$$
Then $f_n$ is continuous functions such that $0\leq f_n \leq 1$ (i.e. uniformly bounded) and $f(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) = 1_{(0,1/2]}(x)$. Furthermore, set $P_n=\delta_{1/n}, P=\delta_0$ some Dirac deltas. We have checked above that $P_n\rightarrow P$ weakly. However, we have
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int f d P_n =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(1/n)=1 \neq 0 = f(0) = \int f dP.  $$
